# How do I update a listview in a fragment without restarting the app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a ListView that lists the non-system apps running in the background. I want this to update as new apps are started and closed. I'm not sure how I would apply other answers so I figured I should ask.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private final Fragment mTimerFragment = new TimerFragment();
private final Fragment mListFragment = new ListFragment();
private final Fragment mReminderFragment = new RemindFragment();

private Fragment mActiveFragment = mTimerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragContainer, mReminderFragment, "TimerFragment")
        .hide(mReminderFragment)
        .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragContainer, mListFragment, "ListFragment")
        .hide(mListFragment)
        .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragContainer, mTimerFragment, "ReminderFragment")
        .commit();

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.navigation_home:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .hide(mActiveFragment)
        .show(mTimerFragment)
        .commit();
        mActiveFragment = mTimerFragment;
        return true;

        case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .hide(mActiveFragment)
        .show(mListFragment)
        .commit();
        mActiveFragment = mListFragment;
        return true;

        case R.id.navigation_notifications:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .hide(mActiveFragment)
        .show(mReminderFragment)
        .commit();
        mActiveFragment = mReminderFragment;
        return true;
        }

        return false;
        }
        }
```

I'm using a bottom navigation with three fragments. The fragment in question is this one :

**Fragment**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_list,null);
        ListView list1 = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();

        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfo = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        final String pnArr[] = new String[runningAppProcessInfo.size()];
        List<String> filteredApps = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> filteredRunningApps = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<>();

        //user-apps loop
        List<PackageInfo> apps = getActivity().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++){
            if ((apps.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 1){
                filteredApps.add(apps.get(i).packageName);
            }
        }

        //running apps + comparison loop
        for (int i = 0; i < runningAppProcessInfo.size(); i++) {
            pnArr[i] = runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName;
            if (filteredApps.contains(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName)) {
                filteredRunningApps.add(runningAppProcessInfo.get(i).processName);
            }
        }

        //package name -> app name conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < filteredRunningApps.size();i++) {
            ApplicationInfo ai = null;
            try{
                ai = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(filteredRunningApps.get(i),0);

            }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){}
            String title = (String)((ai != null) ? packageManager.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "???");
            appNames.add(title);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Filtered Apps : " + filteredApps.size() + " | Running Apps : " + runningAppProcessInfo.size() + " | Filtered Running Apps : " + filteredRunningApps.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         ArrayList<String> pnList = new ArrayList<String>();
         pnList.addAll(Arrays.asList(pnArr));
         ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,appNames);
         list1.setAdapter(aa);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The way it works right now is it gets the list when the application starts but it stays that way until the application is restarted and the list is populated with new values. Any idea how to make it update when applications in the background are closed / opened?

Comment: Everytime you add data to your list you should, call the notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when you update your data.

So in your case it would be afterthis line

```
  appNames.add(title);
```

You add this

```
  aa.notifyDataSetChanged()
```